# Issues reading data from a CSV - Sorting and formatting issues

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

Within VB.NET, I'm trying to load a CSV file into a DataTable that will eventually be pulled into a DataGridView.

The problem that I keep running into is the formatting of the data pulled from the CSV file.

All the data is read as strings which is a problem when I wish to sort columns containing numbers. They all seem to be sorted alphabetically instead of numerically.

So I cloned the DataTable and set some columns to `.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")` and some columns to `.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")`

But then I ran into a new issue with my data not being able to fit in those new DataType columns.

Some of my columns of data contain numbers like these:

```
2,090
1,129
5,324
```

And some columns contain data like these:

```
1.82%
5.34%
54.32%
```

I have a large amount of data - at least 20,000 rows or more so I would like to avoid looping through each row and then each column in order to convert the value to the correct format.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should parse these values while loading the records from the `CSV` file. Possibly, use a parser as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It lets you use a class structure to map the CSV string fields to class Properties with a couple of commands.

Comment: Setting the `DataType` of the column doesn't magically change the data in it. If you want to work with numbers then it's up to you to make sure that you have numbers. If you're pasring the text that you read from the file manually then you have to actually convert the `String` objects to `Integer` or `Decimal` or whatever. As suggested, there are some libraries that will do that work for you.

Comment: *"I would like to avoid looping through each row and then each column in order to convert the value"*. Which is why you need to convert it as you read it, before you put it into the `DataTable` at all.

Comment: What you might want to do is create the datatable with appropriate column data types *before* you load the CSV file, assuming the file format is stable and known in advance. You have not mentioned how you are loading that file to the datatable.

Comment: I have tried CsvHelper but I run into issues like these:
`CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: 'The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: '50.00%'
    MemberType: System.Decimal
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DecimalConverter''`

Comment: This: `50.00%` is not a decimal, it's a formatted string containing a symbol. The percent symbol shouldn't be in the data source in the first place. You can trim these artifacts yourself, though. Something like: `Dim trimmingChars = New Char() {"%"c, "$"c} Dim percentInput As String = "50.00%".Trim(trimmingChars)`. Apply to the *value type* Fields. Add more symbols to the array of chars if needed, without cutting off parts of other type of Fields (Fields that are not meant to represent a *number*). Currency symbols should be parsed correctly, though.

Comment: I know that I need to remove these characters but how do I do this without having to loop through each row and field?

Comment: With a [Type Conversion](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion) or an [Inline Type Conversion](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/inline-type-conversion) or [Reading by Hand](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand) or ... (see the Docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue that I was having with the help of [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

This is how I solved it

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form2

    Public Sub LoadCsvFile3(fileName As String)
        MyDataGridView.Columns.Clear()
        MyDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(fileName)
        Dim csv As New CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, New CultureInfo("en-US"))
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(Of MyColumnsMap)()
        Dim records = csv.GetRecords(Of MyColumns).ToList

        Dim myDataTable As DataTable
        myDataTable = ToDataTable(records)
        MyDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable
        MyDataGridView.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Function ToDataTable(Of T)(data As IList(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim properties As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(T))
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        For i As Integer = 0 To properties.Count - 1
            Dim [property] As PropertyDescriptor = properties(i)
            dt.Columns.Add([property].Name, [property].PropertyType)
        Next
        Dim values As Object() = New Object(properties.Count - 1) {}
        For Each item As T In data
            For i As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
                values(i) = properties(i).GetValue(item)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(values)
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyColumns
    Public Property MyWord As String
    Public Property MyNumber As Integer
    Public Property MyPercent As Decimal
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class MyColumnsMap
    Inherits CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap(Of MyColumns)
    Sub New()
        Map(Function(x) x.MyWord).Name("My Words")
        Map(Function(x) x.MyNumber).Name("My Numbers") _
            .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(New CultureInfo("en-US")) _
            .TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Number)
        Map(Function(x) x.MyPercent).Name("My Percents") _
            .ConvertUsing(Function(Row)
                              Dim trimmingChars = New Char() {"%"c, "$"c}
                              Return Row.GetField(Of String)("CTR").Trim(trimmingChars)
                          End Function)
    End Sub
End Class
```